# Can the client get the URL from a $.get() jQuery call?

Tags: jquery, url, get, intercept

Can the client easily intercept or extract the exact URL used in the URL **variable** (ie: **someURL**) in a `$.get()` call?  Note that the URL in the `$.get(someURL)` call is not hard-coded and is applied to **someURL** after this completed/done call:

```
$.getJSON('https://yes.youcanfreelyseethis.url', function(data) {
    someURL = data[0];

    $.get(someURL, function(someData) {
    });
});
```

**Do assume** that the user will not be able to navigate directly to the URL in $.getJSON() if they enter it in their URL bar for example.

How about **`someData`**?  Can the client see what that value is if it is not being used?

Comment: Every request can be seen in browser dev tools network and therefore it's url and data also. So not really clear what sort of security you are asking about here. Anyone can also add a user script to act as ajax interceptor to log whatever they want from those requests or send the info somewhere else

Comment: ok, got it.  So basically, the values in JavaScript variables/constants can be viewed easily using the development tools.  I will give it a go and see if I can do it myself.  IF it requires some special steps to get there, if you can list those steps.  I'm using the latest Firefox browser but have Chrome also.